# small chains guarantee existence of big independent set?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I can't figure out whether the hypothesis below holds. If you know the answer (or else the decidability), I would love to get a hint towards understanding it.

**Definition.** If $(P,\prec)$ is a partially ordered set and $I\subset P$, then $I$ is called an *independent subset* of $P$ if for all $x,y\in I$ we have $x\prec y$ nor $y\prec x$. For the sake of clarity, this means: not ($x\prec y$ or $y\prec x$).

**Hypothesis.** Assume GCH, let $\kappa\geq\mu^{++}$ be regular, and let $\prec$ be a partial order on $\kappa$ such that every $\prec$-chain has cardinality at most $\mu$. Then $\kappa$ has an independent subset of cardinality $\kappa$.

I included GCH because of the following counterexample for $\kappa=2^\mu$:
Let $\prec'$ be the lexicographic ordering on $2^\mu$, let $<$ be a wellordering of $2^\mu$ and set ${\prec}={\prec'}\cap{<}$. Every $\prec$-chain is a $\prec'$-chain so it has cardinality at most $\mu$, but every ($\prec$-)independent subset is also a $\prec'$-chain and thus has cardinality at most $\mu$.

**Proof for $\mu<\omega$.** By induction. The cases $\mu=0$ and $\mu=1$ are trivial.

$\mu\geq2$: Let $B=\{\zeta\in\kappa:\exists\lambda\in\kappa:\zeta\prec\lambda\}$. Then $\kappa\setminus B$ is clearly an independent subset. We may therefore assume that $|B|=\kappa$. We apply the induction hypothesis with $B,\prec|B$ replacing $\kappa,\prec$ respectively to find a $\prec$-chain $C=\{c_1\prec\dots\prec c_{\mu-1}\}$ in $B$ of length $\mu-1$. By definition of $B$ there is $\zeta\in\kappa$ with $c_{\mu-1}\prec\zeta$; $C\cup\{\zeta\}$ is a $\prec$-chain in $\kappa$ of cardinality $\mu$.

Comment: "nor" or "neither + nor"? Currently the definition of "independent set" makes no sense. It seems to be the definition of an anti-chain, by the way.

Comment: hi Asaf, yea, with "A nor B" I mean "not (A or B)". You're right, anti-chain and independent set is the same thing

Comment: You should [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I found a weaker statement which could be relatively superficial, but which is still quite satisfying for me at the moment. If you want, feel free to check the validity of the proof.

**Lemma.** Let $\kappa>2^\mu$ and let $\prec$ be an asymmetric relation on $\kappa$ such that every subset that is totally ordered by $\prec$ has cardinality $<\mu$. Then there is an independent subset $I\subset\kappa$ of cardinality $\mu$ (independent again means that for all $x,y\in I$, $x\prec y$ nor $y\prec x$).

**Proof.** The idea is that we keep splitting up the set $\kappa$ so that elements that have not been separated, agree (regarding $\prec$) on a certain growing set. We do this $\mu$ times, and then there have to be some unseparated elements left (this will be called $A_\delta$ at the end of the proof); the growing set below this, which will be the image of $\phi$, is then homogeneous enough to forcedly contain either a chain or an independent set of cardinality $\mu$.

Let $c$ be a choice function on $\mathcal{P}\kappa\setminus\{\emptyset\}$. For every $\zeta\leq\mu$ and $\alpha\in3^\zeta$ we define a subset $A_\alpha\subset\kappa$ such that

1. $A_\emptyset=\kappa$;
2. $A_\alpha\subset A_\beta$ for $\alpha\supset\beta$;
3. $A_\alpha\cap A_\beta=\emptyset$ for $\alpha,\beta\in3^\zeta(\alpha\neq\beta)$;
4. $|A_\beta\setminus\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^\zeta}A_\alpha|\leq2^\mu$ for all $\beta\in3^\xi$ and $\xi\leq\zeta$;
5. $(x\prec c(A_\beta)\Leftrightarrow \alpha(\xi)=0)$ and $(c(A_\beta)\prec x\Leftrightarrow \alpha(\xi)=2)$ for all $\xi<\zeta$, $\beta\in3^\xi$, $\alpha\in3^\zeta$, $\beta\subset\alpha$, $x\in A_\alpha$.

Suppose that we have defined $A_\beta$ where $\beta\in3^\zeta$. We write $\beta[r]=\beta\cup\{(\zeta,r)\}$ for $r\in3$. If $A_\beta=\emptyset$ we set $A_{\beta[r]}=A'_\beta=\emptyset$ for all $r$. Otherwise, let $A'_\beta=A_\beta\setminus\{c(A_\beta)\}$, $A_{\beta[0]}=\{a\in A'_\beta:a\prec c(A_\beta)\}$, $A_{\beta[2]}=\{a\in A'_\beta:c(A_\beta)\prec a\}$ and $A_{\beta[1]}=A'_\beta\setminus(A_{\beta[0]}\cup A_{\beta[2]})$.

If $\zeta$ is a limit ordinal and $\alpha\in3^\zeta$, let
$$
A_\alpha=\bigcap_{\xi<\zeta}A_{\alpha|\xi}.
$$
This completes the definition of the sets $A_\alpha$.

It is clear that 2 and 3 hold.

Let's verify 4. Let $\xi$ and $\beta$ be fixed. It is trivial for $\xi=\zeta$. Suppose that it holds for certain $\zeta$. Then
$$
\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^{\zeta+1}}A_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^\zeta}(A_{\alpha[0]}\cup A_{\alpha[1]}\cup A_{\alpha[2]})=
\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^\zeta}A'_\alpha
$$
so
$$
\left|A_\beta\setminus\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^{\zeta+1}}A_\alpha\right|\leq\left|A_\beta\setminus\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^\zeta}A_\alpha\right|+|3^\zeta|\leq2^\mu.
$$
Now if $\zeta$ is a limit ordinal, we claim that
$$
\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^\zeta}A_\alpha
$$
contains $A_\beta\setminus\{c(A_\gamma):\eta<\zeta,\gamma\in3^\eta(A_\gamma\neq\emptyset)\}$.
If $x$ is an element of this last set, we apply the induction hypothesis on this last claim to find for each $\xi\leq\eta<\zeta$ an $\alpha_\eta$ with $\beta\subset\alpha_\eta\in3^\eta$ and $x\in A_\eta$. 2 and 3 yield $\eta<\eta'\implies\alpha_\eta\subset\alpha_{\eta'}$. For $\delta:=\bigcup_\eta\alpha_\eta$ we have
$$
x\in\bigcap_{f\in\zeta^{(3^\zeta)}}A_{\delta|f(\delta)}\subset\bigcap_{f\in\zeta^{(3^\zeta)}}\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^\zeta}A_{\alpha|f(\alpha)}
=\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^\zeta}\bigcap_{\eta<\zeta}A_{\alpha|\eta}=\bigcup_{\beta\subset\alpha\in3^\zeta}A_\alpha.
$$
This proofs 4.

To verify 5, note by 2 that $x\prec c(A_\beta)\Leftrightarrow x\in A_{\beta[0]}$. By 2 and 3, this is equivalent to $\alpha(\xi)=0$. The second statement is similar.

We now construct the subset $I$. By 1 and 4,
$$
\left|\bigcup_{\alpha\in3^\mu}A_\alpha\right|=\kappa.
$$
Thus there exists $\delta\in3^\mu$ such that $A_\delta\neq\emptyset$. Let $\phi(\zeta)=c(A_{\delta|\zeta})$ for $\zeta\leq\mu$. There are three cases.

1. $|\delta^{-1}\{0\}|=\mu$: let $C=\phi(\delta^{-1}\{0\})$. We prove that $C$ is totally ordered by $\prec$ and of cardinality $\mu$ by showing that $\phi:(\delta^{-1}\{0\},<)\rightarrow(\kappa,\prec)$ is order-reversing. Let $\xi,\zeta\in\delta^{-1}\{0\}$ with $\xi<\zeta$ and note that $\phi(\zeta)\prec\phi(\xi)$ by 5.
2. $|\delta^{-1}\{2\}|=\mu$: this case is similar to case 1.
3. $|\delta^{-1}\{1\}|=\mu$: let $I=\phi(\delta^{-1}\{1\})$. By the same arguments as in the previous cases, $I$ is an independent subset. To show that $|I|=\mu$, let $\xi,\zeta\in\delta^{-1}\{1\}$ with $\xi<\zeta$ and note by 2 that $\phi(\zeta)\in A_{\delta|\xi+1}\subset A'_{\delta|\xi}$ so $\phi(\zeta)\neq\phi(\xi)$.

The proof is complete.